# Pass data from Parent Component to nested Child Component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am having difficulties understanding how to make data available between Angular `components`. I have read up on `@Input` and `@Output`, but I am not sure whether this is what I need to use, and if so, how.

I have a parent `component` (an Asset with unique `assetId`), with a nested (child) `component` that should list all the documents related to the specific `asset`, based upon the `assetId`.

**How can I pass the `assetId` from the `asset component` to the `document` `component` to use for fetching the required data for the specific record?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template solution:

**asset.component.ts**:

```
@Input() assetId: string;
```

Usage of `asset`:

```
<asset assetId="x"></asset>
```

**document.component.ts**:

```
@Input() assetId: string;
```

**asset.component.html**:

```
<document [assetId]="assetId"></document>
```

Basically it just passes down the assetId to `document` which resides in `asset`'s template.

**EDIT**

Component only solution:

```
export class AssetComponent {
  @ViewChild(DocumentComponent) document: DocumentComponent;
  @Input() set assetId(assetId) {
    this._assetId = assetId;
    this.document.assetId = assetId;
  } 

  get assetId() {
    return this._assetId;
  }

  private _assetId: string;
}
```

Here you pick up the `DocumentComponent` via `ViewChild` and access its `assetId` property via the `document` instance. Make sure that `assetId` in `DocumentComponent` is `public`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. How can I pass the id from the parent to the child without using the HTML? I have read something about @Injectable

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is definately more inline with what I need. Just to clarify; when I assign the following: `this.document.assetId = assetId;` - does this value get passed to a variable with the name assetId in the Document.component.ts?

Comment: @onmyway Yes. It will bind it to either an `@Input()` variable or a normal class property.